# Tocloft + KOMA, get rid of numberings in table of content, but keep them in the content

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, koma-script, tocloft

I am using the documentclass `scrbook` (KOMA) with `tocloft` and would like to get rid of all the numberings of the chapters, sections and subsections in the table of content, but not in the content itself. How can I do that? I searched a lot, but couldn't find anything.

I tried

```
 \renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
```

but then all the numberings will disappear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply redefine the LaTeX/`scrbook` macro `\numberline` which is responsible for typesetting the number in  `\contentsline`. (Sectioning entries in the header/footer will keep their number.)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

% Original LaTeX definition
% \def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\hfil}}

% scrbook definition
% \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{%
%   \numberline@box{%
%     \numberline@prefix\numberline@numberformat{#1}\numberline@postfix
%   }%
% }

% Variant A -- without number, but with indentation
% \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{%
%   \numberline@box{%
%     \numberline@prefix\numberline@numberformat{}\numberline@postfix
%   }%
% }

% Variant B -- without number and indentation
\renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\subsection{foobargnu}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a follow up problem described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51643/tocloft-koma-get-rid-of-numberings-in-table-of-content-but-keep-them-in-the).

Answer (score 0):

Since [KOMA-Script Version 3.20](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) (current on CTAN) it is possible to remove the entry numbers in TOC using `\RedeclareSectionCommands`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2016/05/10]
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\remove[1]{}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  %tocindent=0pt,% if the indentation should also be removed
  tocnumwidth=0pt,
  tocentrynumberformat=\remove
]{part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}
\section{foobar}
\subsection{foobargnu}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

And with `tocindent=0pt`

[image]