# Tocloft + KOMA, get rid of numberings in table of content, but keep them in the content and in other lists such as list of figures

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, koma-script, tocloft

I am using the documentclass scrbook (KOMA) with tocloft and would like to get rid of all the numberings of the chapters, sections and subsections in the table of content, but not in the content and as well not in the other lists I will have (such as list of figures, list of terms, list of mentioned authors etc.) themselves.

There is already a similar question posed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51517/tocloft-koma-get-rid-of-numberings-in-table-of-content-but-keep-them-in-the), but now I would like to get a solution for this specific case. Here is a solutions, which disables all numberings in all lists by lockstep. But as mentioned above I need one, where I could specify it for each category of lists (list of figures, list of xxxx. etc.).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

% Without number and indentation
\renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you redefine `\numberline` to do nothing (or more precisely, to gobble its argument), make a copy named, say, `\oldnumberline`. Then use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch the internal LaTeX macro `\@caption` (which is used for floats like `figure` and `table`) to use `\oldnumberline` instead of `\numberline`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\numberline}{\oldnumberline}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\subsection{foobargnu}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class. You can use option

```
toc=indenttextentries
```

and redefine `\addtocentrydefault` to get ride of all entry numbers in TOC.

```
\renewcommand\addtocentrydefault[3]{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{\nonumberline#3}}
```

And you can use

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section,indent=0pt]{chapter}
```

locally to avoid an automatic page break before the list starts.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[toc=indenttextentries]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\addtocentrydefault[3]{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{\nonumberline#3}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section,indent=0pt]{chapter}
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
\endgroup

\chapter{foo}
\section{foobar}
\subsection{foobargnu}
\lipsum
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update**

Starting with [KOMA-Script version 3.20](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) you can use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to remove the entry numbers in TOC.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2016/05/10]
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\remove[1]{}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocnumwidth=0pt,
  tocentrynumberformat=\remove
]{part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{foo}
\section{foobar}
\subsection{foobargnu}
\lipsum
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]